# How to generate / create my own PHP CLI command

Tags: php, command-line-interface

On most of PHP frameworks, they have our CLI PHP command to do something (Create controller, create database ... etc).

I have a framework created from scratch, for that, I want to create my own CLI PHP command to easier my work.

I search a lot for this point, but unfortunately no information I get it.

Is there any solution? or method to do it?

Comment: You just need to write any script and run it. You can autorun them without explicitly wrting php with #!/usr/bin/env php at the begining of the file. Anything more complicated is up to you.

Comment: https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Cli - Not really a appropriate question, but lucky for you I made this thing.

Comment: Here is another project of mine (I just did) that uses this library, you can use it as an example if you want https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/SCSS

Comment: Laravel Zero or splitbrain come to my mind

Answer (score 2):

After answers of users,

You can create your own CLI Command by creating a PHP script and call it with this command : `php nameofyouscript.php` or you can create a file without extension and add `#!/usr/bin/env php` on the first line and write you php code, to call it you can use this command : `php nameofyourscript`

To receive information from user you can add this line to you php code :

```
$line = readline("Write something: ");
echo $line
```

Finally, if you want to create a command like this `php nameofyouscript something` you can add this on you php code :

```
echo $argv[1]; //to get 'something'
```

PS: If you have any other information please edit this comment or write your own.

I hope that can help.